# How to make that MATE runs a command at session startup?

Tags: x11, startup, mouse, mate-desktop

**Question**-
  *How to run a command at startup?*
**Background info**

I have a problem with the tap to click action that isn’t enabled, so that it's solved using

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

But every time the computer starts I have to run manually the command. I have added the line to the .bashrc file, added it to the mate-session-properties, looked for the xinitrc, but there is only a xinitrc.template that I’m not sure this is the one the system is using, and all of that doesn’t work. I hope this won't have to be added to the rc services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run a command at startup in MATE Desktop is going to *Control Center -> Startup Applications -> + Add* and then you can insert your command. But in your specific case it won't work, when you will wake up your computer from suspend the tap to click action will not work again. The best way to enable tap to click is going in *Control Center -> Mouse -> Touchpad -> Enable mouse clicks with touchpad*.

Comment: While this answers the specific use case of the original question, it does not address the general title of the post. Not sure how to resolve this, as users searching for this general topic, but not the specific Mouse Touchpad Click, issue won't be helped.

Comment: @0xSheepdog, agreed!  I am just such a user!  My search continues...